# Proving that any two consecutive elements of codomain of a function are relatively prime

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

$h$ is defined as follows: $ h(1) = h(2) = 1; h(n) = (h(n-1))^2 + h(n-2)$ if $n > 2$.

Prove that for all n>1 that the $gcd(h(n), h(n-1)) = 1$.

---

My attempt with proof by induction:

Let $P(n)$ be the statement that $gcd(h(n), h(n-1)) = 1$.

$P(2)$ is true because $gcd(h(2),h(1)) = gcd(1,1) = 1$

Assume $P(n)$. We shall prove $P(n+1)$.

We know that gcd(a,b) = gcd(b,r) if there exists q and r ints such that a = bq+r .

Thus, $gcd(h(n+1),h(n)) = gcd(h(n),h(n-1)),$ where $h(n+1) = a$, $h(n) = b$, and $h(n-1) = r$.

(from the function definition seemed to fit $a=bq+r$, with $b=q$)

By the inductive hypothesis, $gcd(h(n), h(n-1)) = 1$

Hence, P(n+1) is True.

Any flaws?

Comment: This is incorrect. When you divide h(n+1) to h(n) you don't know that the remainder is h(n-1).

Comment: isn't the function defined in basically a = bq +r form? with b = q each time. So h(n+1) = h(n)^2 + h(n-1) ?  h(5) = 27, h(4) = 5, and h(3) = 2.   27=5*5 +3.  r =3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $d>1$ divides both $h(n)$ and $h(n-1)$. Then from the function definition, $d$ divides $h(n-2)$. Then it divides $h(n-3)$ and so on, you go back as much as needed... finally $d$ divides $h(1)$ which is $1$. Contradiction (since $d>1$).